# Flot - Donut Pie Chart - Customize legend

Tags: charts, flot, legend, pie-chart

I created a Donut Pie chart using [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-pie/index.html).

[image: example of my chart]

Is there a way to customize "Legend"?   I want to GFavorite, G2 and G3 to font to be bold. I added:

```
pie: { 
    innerRadius: 0.5, 
    show: true, 
    formatter: function(label, series){ 
        return '<div style="font-style:bold">'; 
    }
}
```

But it does not do anything.

Comment: The legend uses the `label` assigned to the series but it looks like you already know that.  So, what sort of "customization" are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use this:

```
labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
    // series is the series object for the label
    return '<span style="font-style:bold">' + label + '</span>';
}
```

Comment: Dear Mark, sorry for being late. Thank you very much

Comment: @Mark, Hey there, Would you be interested in some jquery tasks?

Answer (score 3):

The CSS is incorrect...

```
font-weight
```

is the proper tag for using bold, not font-style.

see:  http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/font-weight